# how to configure network in cisco routing and switching?

Tags: cisco, router, switch

I am working at hotel and resort, and I want to build network for the hotel using cisco router and switch. the hotel customers number is up to 100 per day and there is 50 rooms. but i want to know each steps to configure the cisco router and switch to manage the lan and wireless network as needed. pleasy help me with easly setup and configuration procedures, i have little knowledge on it.

Comment: Do you already own the Cisco equipment, or do you have a chance to buy something else? I love my Cisco equipment, but it is not my first choice for introducing a beginner to networking.

Answer (score 2):

Every Cisco device comes with a manual that usually has some basic configuration section. Additionally, you could educate yourself with one of the [many tutorials](https://www.google.fi/search?q=cisco%20switch%20configuration%20tutorial) around the subject. For a Q/A site creating such configuration is way too broad.

In your hotel environment you wouldn't want your customers to see each other's computers i.e. you'd create a *client isolation*. For this, [Isolated Private VLANs](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/lan-switching/private-vlans-pvlans-promiscuous-isolated-community/40781-194.html) may become handy.

If, using these resources, you aren't still able to configure your devices, you may need to hire a specialist. If you only face some minor problems, they'd fit on Server Fault.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no general clue about how to build a network you should hire a professional.

Alternatively, learn the basic skills of switching, routing, network design, security and how to do all that with the equipment you intend.

You aren't expecting a comprehensive introduction in 50 words, are you?